# Python: SQLAlchemy Query Filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having a lot of trouble with the SQLAlchemy query filter and I wonder if someone could help me (please go easy, I'm still learning)...

models.py:

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(150))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(150))
    company = db.Column(db.String(150))
    position = db.Column(db.String(150))
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    number = db.Column(db.String(150))
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    status = db.Column(db.String(150))


class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner = db.Column(db.String(150))
    identification = db.Column(db.String(150))
    serialnumber= db.Column(db.String(150))
```

views.py (shortened to show the db query)

```
records = Item.query.filter_by(owner=current_user.company).all()
```

I then pass records with the render_template function.

The problem I am having is that if I query as such:

```
records = Item.query.all()
```

All records are returned perfectly fine but when using the filter (or filter_by) I always get nothing. I have checked my db and made sure that the field contains the correct text and its exactly the same so it should filter but never does.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try printing the `repr` of the value that you are passing to the filter, and of the actual value in the database.  There could be some leading or trailing whitespace preventing the filter from matching.

Comment: Thanks so much, it was down to a stupid spelling mistake that I just couldn't see.